# Auto Generate Unit Tests From Swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger, mocha.js

How can we generate unit tests from Swagger file. Do we have any npm module that solves. I tried searching in npm repository and i don't see one. I am looking for modules or paid tools that can generate mocha based unit tests from swagger yaml file.

Any pointers in this direction is greatly helpful. If there are none, I am thinking to write one. But, instead of reinventing the wheel again, I am searching for any existing solutions.